# Calculating cell resistance in dependence from cell temperature from CAN bus logs

Tags: batteries, can, matlab, data, python

I'm part of a formula student team. When we go testing we are logging the CAN bus data the car produces to further understand what the car is doing.

We log all the battery cell temperatures/voltages and the current going trough the cells. With this data I want to calculate the resistance as a function of the temperature. In the laboratory this task is easy since you have a constant current going through the cells. With the voltage drop over the cell you can easily calculate the resistance. Unfortunately this is not possible with the logs since the current is always changing.

[image: Voltage of an individual cell]

[image: Temperature of an individual cell]

[image: Current(green) vs. Accumulator Voltage (blue)]

### Things I've tried:

1. Get all the voltages when no current is flowing. Connect this data. Then try to guess a resistance of the cells so the actual voltage and voltage with no current is lining up. This approach while giving decent results neglects the dynamic nature of the cells.

### The "ideal" approach:

Creating a bode plot of the current as input and the voltage as output. Then fitting a model of a cell onto that plot. This model has a resistance parameter. Also other parameters like capacitance could be measured this way. Being a frequency analysis, this would show all the dynamic behavior of a cell. Doing this in 30s parts to the whole signal and assigning the parameters to the mean temperature of that period would get the temperature dependence.

Available tools:

- Python(favored)
- MATLAB R2018a
- Any free program/language

Also any suggestions or insights would be great!

Here is the data in pickle format (Python): https://classic.hidrive.com/lnk/rZHA1ahy

Here is the data in MATLAB format: https://classic.hidrive.com/lnk/tdng1sOb (just rename it .mat)

Comment: Also the cell resistance changes depending on the charge state, not only the temperature.

Comment: Though the data comes from messages send out on a CAN bus, this question is really not about CAN bus (and thus should be retagged) - if the data was recorded by some other means it would make no difference to this question.

Comment: If it helps I don‘t mind removing the tag. On the other hand part of the question is about processing the CAN-data, which is different from for example simulation data.

Comment: Resistance as a function of the temperature? Isn't it dependent on the voltage as well (that is, the charge state of the battery)?

Comment: What Formula? [Formula Student](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_motorsport#21st_century_renaissance) (mixed)?

Comment: Its the formula student yes and since our car runs on batteries we are part of the formula student electric. For me the most important aspect is the dependance on temperature, but if we could determine another dependance that would be great.